# How to make a pyplot window larger than the screen and scroll-able

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I'm working on image analysis and would like to display many variations on manipulations to an image.

When I use matplotlib.pyplot the images automatically shrink to the screen size. I prefer they reach below the screen and be scroll-able.

In bokeh the images are in poor resolution and after a certain amount of images the browser shows a blank due to memory issues:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Source is too large
layout.html:189 'CanvasRenderingContext2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled' is deprecated. Please use 'CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled' instead.
```

Comment: Can you file a support ticket on the [Bokeh issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)? I'm not sure what you mean by "poor resolution" Bokeh will display images as they are given, scaled to the bounds to provide. But if there is something that can be done or explained better (or if there is an actual bug/problem with some number of images) we'd like to fix it. How many images was causing a problem, for instance? Please be a good user of free OSS tools by repaying the devs with detailed information, it's what allow the tools to continue to get better.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `mpld3`

```
pip install mpld3
```

and replace `pyplot.show()` with `mpld3.show()`

super simple